# What CI server and Configuration Management tools I should use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, configuration-management

What CI server and Configuration Management tools I should use
together for a truly development and  deploy maintenance.

There isn't the de facto rails sustainable environment, is there?

Some assumptions:

• code control version ok - git  (de facto tool)
• test framework ok - whatever (rspec is my choice)
• code coverage and analysis ok - whatever (metric-fu, for example)
• server stack ok - (Passenger  for example)
• issue tracker (RedMine)
• etc, ...

I'm want to play if integrity and moonshine projects, for me it's a good
for beginning, isn't it?

What do you think about this?

Thanks,

Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI - I personally prefer Hudson, especially with the Angry Hudson plugin. Its user friendly and has decent reporting metrics.

CM - git

Testing Framework - Dependent on size but, I have our teams write unit tests and have Hudson run the unit test package on code checkin.

Issue Tracker - Trac but, I have not used RedMine